# CSV Filtering a column with mixed data types

Tags: csv, unix, awk, duplicates

I have a CSV with many columns and rows.  Column 4 has some strings and some not.  When I attempt to filter out duplicates it removes ones I want to keep.

When I run:

```
awk -F ',' '!seen[$4]++' oldfile.csv > newfile.csv
```

on

```
71523180,PRASAD  JAMES ANAND, ,#3 ALEX BOYD LINK HILLSBORO
71523190,PRASAD  SHAKUNPALA, ,#3 ALEX BOYD LINK HILLSBORO
71523200,PRASAD  BOBBY UMENDRA, ,#3 ALEX BOYD LINK HILLSBORO
```

it returns what I want:

```
71523180,PRASAD  JAMES ANAND, ,#3 ALEX BOYD LINK HILLSBORO
```

But, when I run that line of code on

```
71508050,"HUNT,  RICHARD F", ,1009 # B FATHOM DR
71508060,"HUNT,  RICHARD F", ,1009 # B FATHOM DR
71561950,"HUNT,  RICHARD F", ,1009 # B FATHOM DR
71562840,"HUNT,  RICHARD F", ,1009 # B FATHOM DR
```

it deletes all those entries.

What to do? Thanks

---

**FOLLOW UP**

Using perl seems to work, but gives me a small error.  Is this an issue?

```
$ perl -w -MText::CSV_XS=csv -e 'csv(in => \*STDIN, filter => { 4 => sub { ! $seen{$_}++ }})' < combined4.csv > combined6.csv
Name "main::seen" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1.
```

Comment: I could not reproduce it, it gives the exact output. Are you sure you have no carriage-returns? I don't think they have anything to do with it, but who knows... Run `dos2unix` on the file just in case.

Comment: @DSL The expected output for your 2nd block of input would be just the first line of input since $4 is a single blank char on all lines. If awk outputs nothing then your awk version is broken. If awk outputs a string you have to print to `cat -v` to see then you have DOS line endings. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45420535/1745001 for more info on the most likely case (the first one I mentioned) and https://stackoverflow.com/q/45772525/1745001 for DOS line endings.

Comment: what's the rule to choose the output record? Is it the first record between all records with the same value for column 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your CSV data is non-trivial, with things like commas inside quoted fields, a tool that's aware of the format is a better option than trying to use `awk` or the like on it.

Example perl one-liner using the [`Text::CSV_XS` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) (Install via your OS package manager or favorite CPAN client):

```
$ perl -MText::CSV_XS=csv -e 'csv(in => \*STDIN, filter => { 4 => sub { ! $seen{$_}++ }})' < input.csv
71508050,"HUNT,  RICHARD F"," ","1009 # B FATHOM DR"
```

Comment: I believe it's the # in the address that's fouling me up.  when the address begins with a # it's fine, but in the middle awk removes all

Comment: @DSL awk sees the column with just a space as the fourth column in your second data set.

Comment: @DSL no, there's nothing special about a `#` in input data.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I see anything wrong what with filtering out nothing as that is in every array even before it is created.

But if you want to keep then all then adding an  "or nothing"
clause would do it.

```
awk -F ',' '!seen[$4]++||$4!=""'
```

Answer (score 1):

using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) on this CSV

```
71523180,PRASAD  JAMES ANAND, ,#3 ALEX BOYD LINK HILLSBORO
71523190,PRASAD  SHAKUNPALA, ,#3 ALEX BOYD LINK HILLSBORO
71523200,PRASAD  BOBBY UMENDRA, ,#3 ALEX BOYD LINK HILLSBORO
71508050,"HUNT,  RICHARD F", ,1009 # B FATHOM DR
71508060,"HUNT,  RICHARD F", ,1009 # B FATHOM DR
71561950,"HUNT,  RICHARD F", ,1009 # B FATHOM DR
71562840,"HUNT,  RICHARD F", ,1009 # B FATHOM DR
```

and running

```
mlr --csv -N sort -f 4 then step -a counter -f 4 -g 4 then filter '$4_counter==1' then cut -x -f 4_counter input.csv >output.csv
```

you will have

```
71523180,PRASAD  JAMES ANAND, ,#3 ALEX BOYD LINK HILLSBORO
71508050,"HUNT,  RICHARD F", ,1009 # B FATHOM DR
```